# Session authentication with react

Tags: asp.net, .net, reactjs, authentication, token

We have a .NET application using session based authenticatino and Razor frontend mostly. Also the ID of the loggedin user and the "burrent project" the user working on are stored in session too.
Now one module of the system is using react. But I can't have access to the sessions of the main app. Is there a way to combine the two, so still use the sessions in the main app, but provide token to the react module?
thanks